# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

periodically when a lot of people(~60) on the site I get such errors:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: UPDATE rooms SET room_profiles_count = COALESCE(`room_profiles_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE rooms.id = 1363
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: DELETE FROM room_profiles WHERE room_profiles.id = 3942
```

I tried to increase the pool to 100, but still get an error
My stack: rails 5, puma, mysql

[here](https://gist.github.com/andiskiy/5b9864fe1039b8bea84f5942b1505213) my configure `puma` & `database.yml`

Tell me, please, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Increase your db connection pool? Optimize your db queries? There's no universal answer to this question.

Comment: How did you increase the pool size? How many servers do you have with this config connecting to the database? Do you use background jobs in your application?

Comment: What do you have RAILS_MAX_THREADS set to?

Comment: You should probably find out where in your code you are locking. If you have 60 users and they could each be potentially doing a locking operation then you would be likely to get timeouts. It's also quite easy to leak active record connections if you are making queries in a different thread. Rails only cleans up connections in the original request thread by default.

Comment: @Slicedpan Hi guys, thanks for your response. I didn't set RAILS_MAX_THREADS, but there are something RAILS_MAX_THREADS || 5. Also I  tried to increase the pool, it didn't help. There can definitely be crooked queries, as the code is very dirty from another developer. I understand that there is no universal answer to this question, I understood this when I was looking for a reason. My temporary workaround crutch: Increase timeout. Thanks for all :)